# Idiomatic Python: Propagating yields or flattening sequences?

Tags: python, yield, tree-traversal

I'm writing a <strike>breadth</strike> depth-first tree traversal function, and what I want to do is this:

```
def traverse(node):
    yield node
    for n in node.children:
        yield_all traverse(n) # << if Python had a yield_all statement
```

The idea is to end up with a (flat) sequence of nodes in the tree.

Approach #1: (propagating yields)

```
def traverse(node):
    yield node
    for n in node.children:
        for m in traverse(n):
            yield m
```

Approach #2: (flattening sequences)

```
def traverse(node):
    return itertools.chain([node],*(traverse(n) for n in node.children))
```

The first approach seems more clean, but I feel weird explicitly `yield`ing each node in the subtree at each level.

The second approach is terse and slightly dirty, but it matches what I would write in Haskell:

```
traverse node = node : concatMap traverse (children node)
```

So my question is: Which is better? Or am I missing a best 3rd option?

Comment: List comprehensions would make this cleaner.

Comment: Rafe: Write an answer and show me! :-)

Comment: I'd like to see a list comprehension for this... you'd need to flatten it in the end, right? As far as I am concerned, the `chain` solution is wonderful.

Comment: Approach #2 does not work. You would get `TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not generator`.

Comment: #2 will not work though .. it chains iterators, `node` is't one.

Comment: @ubuntu: You can do it in 2.7. I think they added it in that version.

Comment: @THC4k, tested in python2.7, and I think @unutbu is right: it should look itertools.chain([node], ...). I have a question here, the *(...) does not break the lazyness of traverse()?

Comment: I agree with delnan that the chain method is probably the best, though you need to make the code be `return itertools.chain([node],*(traverse(n) for n in node.children))` to get it to work (and use list() on traverse(headnode)).

Comment: However, the yield method is about 3x faster than the chain method.. and quite readable so I'd go with that.

Comment: Isn't this depth-first traversal of the tree? Weren't you asking for breadth-first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[UPDATE]** See [PEP-380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/), this *yield all* syntax is available starting from [Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html) as `yield from`:

```
def traverse(node):
    yield node
    for n in node.children:
        yield from traverse(n)
```

Comment: Ah, sometimes it seems everything I wish Python could be is buried in a PEP somewhere.  I should start collecting pep modules, or perhaps just learn to accept that Python isn't *really* a functional language.

Comment: @perimosocordiae: Knowing GvR's opinions on FP I would't expect too much on this angle. But definitely Python would be a sadder language without the FP-related work of Kuchling and Hettinger (and others).

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with first. You'll get over propagating yields after a couple of times. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is an opinions question, so all the answers will just be value judgments. As far as I can think there's no elegant third way, though.

My opinion is that the first way wins hands down. It's clearer and easier to read -- Python isn't Haskell, even though it can do some functional stuff, and often the functional approach just doesn't look as neat.

Answer (score 0):

Traversing with node position:

```
def iter_tree(t, i=0, j=0):
    yield (i, j), t
    for j, n in enumerate(t.children):
        yield from iter_tree(n, i + 1, j)

for (i, j), n in iter_tree(t):
    print(i*'    ', (i, j), n)
```